# Gulp common.js ошибка при добавлении кода

Tags: javascript, gulp

[image: Сам код, что сохраняю в файле common.js]

[image: Собственно сразу же gulp вылетает с данной ошибкой]

Прошу помощи в устранении ошибки, что не так с кодом ? Если его подключить в html - все работает. Заранее спасибо!

Добавил файл сборки:

```
    var gulp           = require('gulp'),
        gutil          = require('gulp-util' ),
        sass           = require('gulp-sass'),
        browserSync    = require('browser-sync'),
        concat         = require('gulp-concat'),
        uglify         = require('gulp-uglify'),
        cleanCSS       = require('gulp-clean-css'),
        rename         = require('gulp-rename'),
        del            = require('del'),
        imagemin       = require('gulp-imagemin'),
        cache          = require('gulp-cache'),
        autoprefixer   = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
        ftp            = require('vinyl-ftp'),
        notify         = require("gulp-notify"),
        rsync          = require('gulp-rsync');

    gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
        browserSync({
            server: {
                baseDir: 'app'
            },
            notify: false,
            // tunnel: true,
            // tunnel: "projectmane", //Demonstration page: http://projectmane.localtunnel.me
        });
    });

// Пользовательские скрипты проекта

gulp.task('common-js', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'app/js/common.js',
        ])
    .pipe(concat('common.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'));
});

gulp.task('js', ['common-js'], function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'app/js/common.min.js', // Всегда в конце
        ])
    .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
    // .pipe(uglify()) // Минимизировать весь js (на выбор)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on("error", notify.onError()))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix : ''}))
    .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
    // .pipe(cleanCSS()) // Опционально, закомментировать при отладке
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'js', 'browser-sync'], function() {
    gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['libs/**/*.js', 'app/js/common.js'], ['js']);
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/img/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin())) // Cache Images
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img')); 
});

gulp.task('build', ['removedist', 'imagemin', 'sass', 'js'], function() {

    var buildFiles = gulp.src([
        'app/*.html',
        'app/.htaccess',
        ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

    var buildCss = gulp.src([
        'app/css/main.min.css',
        ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));

    var buildJs = gulp.src([
        'app/js/scripts.min.js',
        ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));

    var buildFonts = gulp.src([
        'app/fonts/**/*',
        ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));

});

gulp.task('deploy', function() {

    var conn = ftp.create({
        host:      'hostname.com',
        user:      'username',
        password:  'userpassword',
        parallel:  10,
        log: gutil.log
    });

    var globs = [
    'dist/**',
    'dist/.htaccess',
    ];
    return gulp.src(globs, {buffer: false})
    .pipe(conn.dest('/path/to/folder/on/server'));

});

gulp.task('rsync', function() {
    return gulp.src('dist/**')
    .pipe(rsync({
        root: 'dist/',
        hostname: 'username@yousite.com',
        destination: 'yousite/public_html/',
        // include: ['*.htaccess'], // Скрытые файлы, которые необходимо включить в деплой
        recursive: true,
        archive: true,
        silent: false,
        compress: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('removedist', function() { return del.sync('dist'); });
gulp.task('clearcache', function () { return cache.clearAll(); });

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: С кодом все в порядке, у вас падает uglify.js, приложите файл сборки

Comment: Добавил файл сборки